# Unknown parameter "includeObjects" throws exception in command line liquiBase

Tags: database, liquibase

I'm using liquibase 3.3.2 and i'm trying use the "includeObjects" parameter. This is the command line:

```
java -jar liquibase.jar \
 --driver=com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver \
 --url="jdbc:ingres://localhost:21071/local" \
 --username=ingres \
 --password=ingres \
 --logLevel=debug \
 --classpath="iijdbc.jar" \
 "--currentDateTimeFunction=now()" \
 --changeLogFile=db.changelog.xml \
 --defaultSchemaName=ingres \
 --includeObjects=personal \
 generateChangeLog
```

This is the exception thrown.

Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown parameter: 'includeObjects'

SEVERE 24/03/15 10:05 AM: liquibase: Unknown parameter: 'includeObjects'
liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: Unknown parameter: 'includeObjects'
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.parseOptions(Main.java:702)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:124)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:94)

Can anyone point what I am doing wrong?

Supposedly in version 3.3.2 the "includeObject" option is now available: 
[Liquibase 3.3.2 Released](http://blog.liquibase.org/category/announcement)

Answer (score 1):

The option `--includeObjects` is a parameter that belongs to the commands `diff` or `diffChangeLog`.

I guess it can not be used on the command `generateChangeLog`.

Comment: But in the release documentation, they're indicating of explicit way **"It is primarily a bugfix release, but has one major new feature: object diffChangeLog/generateChangeLog object filtering."**

Comment: Hm... Maybe you can try to put the command first and the option to it after the command like so: `generateChangeLog --includeObjects=personal`

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find the solution, thank you very much for the help. Was there another solution to the problem (not related to liquibase for that reason I will not specify)

Answer (score 1):

As [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332248/jens) mentioned in the comment, the following should work as the include/excludeObjects arguments come AFTER the generate/diffChangeLog command apparently:

```
java -jar liquibase.jar \
--driver=com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver \
--url="jdbc:ingres://localhost:21071/local" \
--username=ingres \
--password=ingres \
--logLevel=debug \
--classpath="iijdbc.jar" \
"--currentDateTimeFunction=now()" \
--changeLogFile=db.changelog.xml \
--defaultSchemaName=ingres \
generateChangeLog --includeObjects=personal
```

I did the same approach (with mulitple tables comma-seperated) and it worked fine.